# Using a HashMap to convert Strings to Ints in order to optimize space usage

Tags: java, hashmap, binary-search-tree

I have a program that reads words from text files in a directory. 
The words are then stored into a Binary Search Tree in order to do operations between the files. However, when there are many files and the files are too big, Strings seem to take too much memory.
I would like to optimize space by converting the Strings to ints and I believe a HashMap could help me achieve this but I am not sure how to do so. 
In specific, if I have a HashMap that acts as a dictionary for all the distinct words in all the files, how can I assign them distinct integers that help me create balanced Binary Search Trees?

Comment: You could use something like a [Huffman tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) to compress your words - but you would need some idea about frequencies a priori...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, due to the way HashMaps are implemented in Java, this will not save you space. When you store a value in a HashMap, the hash map actually stores the record as an Entry object, which stores both the value and the key. So using the HashMap will not actually prevent you from having references to these large strings and will not save you memory in your BST implementation.

The reason the key is stored with the value in the Entry object is that perfect hash functions (those which have no collisions) are not practical for hash tables in real world computers. If the hash function assigned a unique hash value to every input, then when you're using an unbounded keyspace (like a string), it would require an infinite amount of memory to store the hash table, because there would be an infinite number of possible address offsets.

Instead, real hash table implementations store the data in a fixed-size array and use an imperfect hash function (one that has collisions, i.e. two inputs can have the same hash value) to assign memory locations, and resizes the array as space starts to get utilized. There are a number of strategies for handling these collisions, such as probing, secondary hash functions, or storing a linked list at each memory location, but all of these methods require knowing what key was used to store the Entry.

In Java's case, the HashMap implementation uses a linked-list approach to handling collisions. When a value is stored for a key, the key gets hashed to determine which 'bucket' the Entry will be placed in. Each bucket is a linked list of Entry objects, and the Entry gets added to the end of that list. When you go to retrieve the value for the key later on, the hash is again computed to tell it which bucket to look in. The linked list nodes are iterated over until the Entry whose key matches the search key is found. Thus, Java needs to store the String when you store something in the HashMap, and there will be no memory saved.

Have you considered profiling your code to make sure the cause of the memory issue is indeed what you think it is? It may be something else, so you should determine the root cause before investing time into coming up with a more complicated implementation to save memory. There are ways you can save memory, but they aren't necessarily going to be trivial to implement, so it's a good idea to make sure these efforts will actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.hashCode()` directly to get the hash code of the string. Nevertheless, note that hash equality does not imply String equality (there will be collisions). So you still need to store the words.

However, using HashMap to store the words will have lower memory requirements than binary search tree, because binary search trees require more memory for each node. But then the structure will not be ordered. So it depends whether you need ordering or not.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a map of word to number, is to ensure that each word is only in memory once.

Calling [`String.intern()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) will have exactly that effect, without the need of a map.
*Note:* [Only for Java 7+](http://java-performance.info/string-intern-in-java-6-7-8/).